# Stream pygame joystick input over socket by sending joystick values to array

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, pygame

I am trying to build a robot that will be controlled through the use of sockets and a joystick in python. I have been trying to send joystick readings from Pygame's sample code into an array but when I print the array I get blank values after moving the axis and pushing buttons. The values appear outside the array but obviously aren't being stored in the array. The code below is what will run on the computer being used to transmit commands to the robot. I've quoted out the lines that will cause errors from not seeing a server. Please help me figure out why I can't get readings from the joystick into an array and please post code snippets, not just word descriptions.

```
import socket      #send data between server and client
import os          #gain control of command prompt features
import keyboard    #read keystrokes
import pygame       #Read Joystick data


os.system('title client')  #rename command prompt
os.system('cls')           #clear command prompt screen

# client = socket.socket()   #constructor

# hostname = '127.0.0.1'  #server ip

# port = 8080   #server open communication port

# client.connect((hostname,port))  #create connection



# Define some colors.
BLACK = pygame.Color('black')
WHITE = pygame.Color('white')


# This is a simple class that will help us print to the screen.
# It has nothing to do with the joysticks, just outputting the
# information.
class TextPrint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

    def tprint(self, screen, textString):
        textBitmap = self.font.render(textString, True, BLACK)
        screen.blit(textBitmap, (self.x, self.y))
        self.y += self.line_height

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.line_height = 15

    def indent(self):
        self.x += 10

    def unindent(self):
        self.x -= 10


pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen (width, height).
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 700))

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Initialize the joysticks.
pygame.joystick.init()

# Get ready to print.
textPrint = TextPrint()

message = []

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    #
    # EVENT PROCESSING STEP
    #
    # Possible joystick actions: JOYAXISMOTION, JOYBALLMOTION, JOYBUTTONDOWN,
    # JOYBUTTONUP, JOYHATMOTION
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close.
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop.
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Joystick button pressed.")
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Joystick button released.")

    #
    # DRAWING STEP
    #
    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    textPrint.reset()

    # Get count of joysticks.
    joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()

    textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of joysticks: {}".format(joystick_count))
    textPrint.indent()

    # For each joystick:
    for i in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
        joystick.init()

        try:
            jid = joystick.get_instance_id()
        except AttributeError:
            # get_instance_id() is an SDL2 method
            jid = joystick.get_id()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Joystick {}".format(jid))
        textPrint.indent()

        # Get the name from the OS for the controller/joystick.
        name = joystick.get_name()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Joystick name: {}".format(name))

        # try:
        #     guid = joystick.get_guid()
        # except AttributeError:
        #     # get_guid() is an SDL2 method
        #     pass
        # else:
        #     textPrint.tprint(screen, "GUID: {}".format(guid))

        # Usually axis run in pairs, up/down for one, and left/right for
        # the other.
        axes = joystick.get_numaxes()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of axes: {}".format(axes))
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range(axes):
            axis = joystick.get_axis(i)
            textPrint.tprint(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(i, axis))
            message.append(joystick.get_axis(i))
        textPrint.unindent()

        buttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of buttons: {}".format(buttons))
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range(buttons):
            button = joystick.get_button(i)
            textPrint.tprint(screen, "Button {:>2} value: {}".format(i, button))
            message.append(button)
        textPrint.unindent()

        hats = joystick.get_numhats()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of hats: {}".format(hats))
        textPrint.indent()

        # Hat position. All or nothing for direction, not a float like
        # get_axis(). Position is a tuple of int values (x, y).
        for i in range(hats):
            hat = joystick.get_hat(i)
            textPrint.tprint(screen, "Hat {} value: {}".format(i, str(hat)))
        textPrint.unindent()

        textPrint.unindent()

        
        #Display values recorded in array
        for i in message:
        value = message[int(i)]
        textPrint.tprint(screen,"values: {}".format(value))

    #
    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT
    #

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 20 frames per second.
    clock.tick(20)

# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
pygame.quit()




    # Send to server
    # x = keyboard.read_key()  #read key on keyboard
    # client.send(x.encode())  #send recorded key to server
    # print("You Pressed ", x) #print on client screen the key they pressed
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! The problem was an infinite loop caused by the  "message" array constantly adding to itself because it was outside the loop. By declaring the array inside the "while not done: " loop it would erase itself and add the values where needed. The code now works. Now my only fear is that the value "hat" doesn't cause an issue since it returns 2 values instead of one. I will be marking this case as solved! The fixed code is below in case anyone wants to see where I am so far!

```
import socket      #send data between server and client
import os          #gain control of command prompt features
import keyboard    #read keystrokes
import pygame       #Read Joystick data
import array


os.system('title client')  #rename command prompt
os.system('cls')           #clear command prompt screen

# client = socket.socket()   #constructor

# hostname = '127.0.0.1'  #server ip

# port = 8080   #server open communication port

# client.connect((hostname,port))  #create connection



# Define some colors.
BLACK = pygame.Color('black')
WHITE = pygame.Color('white')


# This is a simple class that will help us print to the screen.
# It has nothing to do with the joysticks, just outputting the
# information.
class TextPrint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

    def tprint(self, screen, textString):
        textBitmap = self.font.render(textString, True, BLACK)
        screen.blit(textBitmap, (self.x, self.y))
        self.y += self.line_height

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.line_height = 15

    def indent(self):
        self.x += 10

    def unindent(self):
        self.x -= 10


pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen (width, height).
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 700))

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Initialize the joysticks.
pygame.joystick.init()

# Get ready to print.
textPrint = TextPrint()

#message = array.array('d',[])

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    



    #clear message
    message = array.array('d',[])
    #
    # EVENT PROCESSING STEP
    #
    # Possible joystick actions: JOYAXISMOTION, JOYBALLMOTION, JOYBUTTONDOWN,
    # JOYBUTTONUP, JOYHATMOTION
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close.
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop.
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Joystick button pressed.")
        elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Joystick button released.")

    #
    # DRAWING STEP
    #
    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    textPrint.reset()

    # Get count of joysticks.
    joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()

    textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of joysticks: {}".format(joystick_count))
    textPrint.indent()

    # For each joystick:
    for i in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
        joystick.init()

        try:
            jid = joystick.get_instance_id()
        except AttributeError:
            # get_instance_id() is an SDL2 method
            jid = joystick.get_id()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Joystick {}".format(jid))
        textPrint.indent()

        # Get the name from the OS for the controller/joystick.
        name = joystick.get_name()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Joystick name: {}".format(name))

        # try:
        #     guid = joystick.get_guid()
        # except AttributeError:
        #     # get_guid() is an SDL2 method
        #     pass
        # else:
        #     textPrint.tprint(screen, "GUID: {}".format(guid))

        # Usually axis run in pairs, up/down for one, and left/right for
        # the other.
        axes = joystick.get_numaxes()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of axes: {}".format(axes))
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range(axes):
            axis = joystick.get_axis(i)
            textPrint.tprint(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(i, axis))
            message.append(joystick.get_axis(i))
        textPrint.unindent()

        buttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of buttons: {}".format(buttons))
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range(buttons):
            button = joystick.get_button(i)
            textPrint.tprint(screen, "Button {:>2} value: {}".format(i, button))
            message.append(button)
        textPrint.unindent()

        hats = joystick.get_numhats()
        textPrint.tprint(screen, "Number of hats: {}".format(hats))
        textPrint.indent()

        # Hat position. All or nothing for direction, not a float like
        # get_axis(). Position is a tuple of int values (x, y).
        for i in range(hats):
            hat = joystick.get_hat(i)
            textPrint.tprint(screen, "Hat {} value: {}".format(i, str(hat)))
        textPrint.unindent()

        textPrint.unindent()

        i = range(len(message))

        textPrint.tprint(screen, "array length {}".format(i))


        for i in range(len(message)):
            value = message[int(i)]
            textPrint.tprint(screen, "value {}: {}".format(i, value))

    #
    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT
    #

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 20 frames per second.
    clock.tick(20)

# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
pygame.quit()




    # Send to server
    # x = keyboard.read_key()  #read key on keyboard
    # client.send(x.encode())  #send recorded key to server
    # print("You Pressed ", x) #print on client screen the key they pressed
```